# PPTP not working

Tags: centos, vpn, pptp, point-to-point-protocol

I keep getting this error when attempting to log on to my new VPN server..

```
Sep  6 14:05:19 378465 pptpd[8171]: CTRL: Starting call (launching pppd, opening GRE)
Sep  6 14:05:19 378465 pppd[8172]: Couldn't open the /dev/ppp device: Permission denied
Sep  6 14:05:19 378465 pppd[8172]: Sorry - this system lacks PPP kernel support
Sep  6 14:05:19 378465 pptpd[8171]: GRE: read(fd=6,buffer=8059660,len=8196) from PTY failed: status = -1 error = Input/output error, usually caused by unexpected termination of pppd, check option syntax and pppd logs
Sep  6 14:05:19 378465 pptpd[8171]: CTRL: PTY read or GRE write failed (pty,gre)=(6,7)
```

Has anybody seen this before? And how did they fix it?

P.S. I am fairly new to MOST linux commands, so please explain well.

Server is CentOS 6

Comment: What is the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Linux *****HOSTNAME**** 2.6.18-348.4.1.el5.028stab107.2 #1 SMP Mon Jul 1 22:13:01 MSD 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

You're using an OpenVZ virtual machine. The hosting provider must specifically enable support for PPP for your virtual machine. Contact your service provider.

Comment: Okay, I am contacting them now. They are usually very slow at responding, but I will update if this fixes it. Thanks!